# Difference between ASP.NET Core Web App templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating a new project when I see that there are two template options. ASP.NET Core Web App and ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller).

In practice, what is the real difference between these 2 layouts?

In both it is possible to work with .NET 7

[image]

Comment: The `ASP.NET Core Web App` template uses **Razor pages** (`.cshtml`) - while the second template uses the "classic" MVC pattern with controllers, models and views for each call. Razor pages is a simplified and "scaled back" version which works just fine for smaller / easier sites when you don't need to full power (and also overhead) of the models, views, and controllers.

Comment: @marc_s so would classic mvc be more robust than Razor Pages?

Comment: Robust is not really a correct term in this context. Building a web site in PHP, or .net, or even asp.net webforms? I would easy state that they are all "similar" in terms of how robust and how well they operate, and that one choice is not really going to break more, or be less (or more) reliable then any other choice you make. It will come down to what coding approach you like the most, and choosing one over the other is not really better or worse. However, as pointed out, Razor pages are somewhat easer to learn and adopt - probably a better choice if coming from webforms.

Answer (score 0):

> **Why Razor Pages?**
>
> Razor Pages is the default approach for new web applications in Visual
> Studio. Razor Pages offers a simpler way of building page-based
> application features, such as non-SPA forms. Using controllers and
> views, it was common for applications to have very large controllers
> that worked with many different dependencies and view models and
> returned many different views. This resulted in more complexity and
> often resulted in controllers that didn't follow the Single
> Responsibility Principle or Open/Closed Principles effectively. Razor
> Pages addresses this issue by encapsulating the server-side logic for
> a given logical "page" in a web application with its Razor markup. A
> Razor Page that has no server-side logic can only consist of a Razor
> file (for instance, "Index.cshtml"). However, most non-trivial Razor
> Pages will have an associated page model class, which by convention is
> named the same as the Razor file with a ".cs" extension (for example,
> "Index.cshtml.cs").
>
> A Razor Page's page model combines the responsibilities of an MVC
> controller and a viewmodel. Instead of handling requests with
> controller action methods, page model handlers like "OnGet()" are
> executed, rendering their associated page by default. Razor Pages
> simplifies the process of building individual pages in an ASP.NET Core
> app, while still providing all the architectural features of ASP.NET
> Core MVC. They're a good default choice for new page-based
> functionality.
>
> **When to use MVC**
>
> If you're building web APIs, the MVC pattern makes more sense than
> trying to use Razor Pages. If your project will only expose web API
> endpoints, you should ideally start from the Web API project template.
> Otherwise, it's easy to add controllers and associated API endpoints
> to any ASP.NET Core app. Use the view-based MVC approach if you're
> migrating an existing application from ASP.NET MVC 5 or earlier to
> ASP.NET Core MVC and you want to do so with the least amount of
> effort. Once you've made the initial migration, you can evaluate
> whether it makes sense to adopt Razor Pages for new features or even
> as a wholesale migration.
>
> Whether you choose to build your web app using Razor Pages or MVC
> views, your app will have similar performance and will include support
> for dependency injection, filters, model binding, validation, and so
> on.

You can also refer to [Compare Razor Pages to ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/comparing-razor-pages-aspnet-mvc) and [Razor Pages vs ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/Rick-Anderson/RP-vs-MVC) to learn more details.